# Clarifying regular expression

Tags: regex

Assuming sentence

> "The time is now 8:15pm. Followed by some other text"

Why would the following regex not match the line?

```
egrep '\<[1-9]\s*:\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[Pp][Mm]\>' file
```

I am on MAC, using GNU egrep

> $ egrep --version egrep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Comment: It does not match. Thought it was clear. I'll update the question

Comment: @JAM I thought it was pretty clear what you meant.  Tough crowd here.

Comment: @jam: "fail" could mean egrep crashes, it erases your harddrive, or it kicks your dog.

Comment: @dbaseman Yup. Tough crowd indeed. Sunday, work tomorrow, whatyagonnado:)

Comment: @MarcB Right. That's what usually happens

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem; there must be something in the "followed by some other text" part that makes the 8:15pm not a word boundary...

Comment: Updated the question. MAC, GNU egrep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Totally unable to reproduce.

Mac OS X 10.7:

```
(0)marks-mac-mini> cat file
The time is now 8:15pm. Followed by some other text
"The time is now 8:15pm. Followed by some other text"
(0)marks-mac-mini> egrep '\<[1-9]\s*:\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[Pp][Mm]\>' file
The time is now 8:15pm. Followed by some other text
"The time is now 8:15pm. Followed by some other text"
(0)marks-mac-mini> egrep --version
egrep (GNU grep) 2.5.1
```

So you're wrong about something somewhere...

**EDIT** Ah, the problem is the space. egrep doesn't recognize `\s`; that's a Perlism.  Your question didn't include the space there.

Comment: Mark, why would the same regex not parse "The time is now 8:15 pm Some text" (Space before pm). When i \s* it fails, when i ` *` it works.

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the leading and trailing symbols in the regex: < and >.  Take those out and it's a match.

Comment: But why is that? Regex seems to work fine all the way until [Pp][Mm]

Comment: @JAM It's pretty simple: having those in the regex pattern requires them to be in the target string.  Perhaps you meant them to be **\b** (word boundary) or something?

Comment: `egrep '[1-9]\s*:\s*[0-9]{2}\s*[Pp]' file` fails to parse as well. No <> present

Comment: @JAM I'm fairly stumped in that case ... I'm testing and it's a match.  Maybe *egrep* uses a different syntax than what I'm used to...

Comment: Weird. I'll try it on Linux tomorrow. Fails on my MAC for some reason

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU egrep on my OS X machine, the expression works just fine and matches your line. It could be your particular version of grep (is it a non-GNU grep?)

Comment: 21:24:04 ~/regex $ egrep --version
egrep (GNU grep) 2.5.1

Comment: Ah, I just saw the question update. Interesting, since it seems to work just fine for me (copy and pasted from the question above).

Comment: @JAM: Using the same version here.